# How can I force user to update the flutter app to latest version?

Tags: flutter, google-play-console

I have uploaded the `Flutter` app with a testing feature that opens the `admin panel` without credentials. I have now corrected the problem but there are some users using the defective version of the app. Is there any way to force user to update the app? Or disable some specific version from the `google play console`?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is not a graceful thing to do.

Comment: block existing API end-points and create new API end-points. You'll need not worry about old versions. It won't work. And users will automatically delete and reinstall. If you have set push notification, send a push notification to update to the latest version after resetting the API end points.

Comment: the app contains a lot of data in firebase. will the data remain protected?

Answer (score 4):

As you have rolled out the faulty application now you cannot force any one to upgrade as that app has no built in feature (also any apk saved would remain vulnerable). Best case is now update your api endpoints to a new endpoint and block the previous endpoints.)

Build a new app:

1. Create new endpoints with authorization at server end so that server can decide what can a user can do instead of just client.
2. use https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_update (Android only) for handling the updates (optional)

3.You can check current app build with a service which forces update (Show a inbuilt screen that the app compulsorily needs to be updated) if server has a greater minimum allowed build number.